# C struct python equivalent

Tags: python, c

I have this C code:

```
    typedef struct test * Test;

    struct test {
        void *a;
        Test next;
    };
```

How would you implement the equivalent to this in Python (if that is even possible)?

Comment: @Eddy_Em What do you smoke right now?

Comment: @glglgl, maybe you can tell me how can I make strict variable type in python? For example: `float a; char *b; void *f; double t;`?

Comment: @Eddy_Em What does this have to do with "being a real programming language"? And why shouldn't it not be possible? Look at the linked "duplicate" question or the answer below - here you see how it would work.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In Python, you can assign objects of any type to a variable; so you can just use any class, like this:

```
class test(object):
    __slots__ = ['a', 'next']

x = test()
x.next = x
x.a = 42
```

Note that [`__slots__`](http://docs.python.org/dev/reference/datamodel.html#slots) is *optional* and should reduce memory overhead (it may also speed up attribute access). Also, you often want to create a constructor, like this:

```
class test(object):
    def __init__(self, a, next):
        self.a = a
        self.next = next

x = test(21, None)
assert x.a == 21
```

If the class can be immutable, you may also want to have a look at [namedtuple](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple):

```
import collections
test = collections.namedtuple('test', ['a', 'next'])
```

Comment: I'm not positive that `__slots__` makes the code run any faster in general (although I suppose it might).  Generally it is used to save memory if you're going to be instantiating hordes of simple objects.